# Issue Regarding SWTException: Invalid Thread Exception|synExec usage is getting failed

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

As it is SWTException, I used the syncExec method , but even I could not ressolve the SWTException issue from my code. Please suggest.

```
public class SampleSwtAction implements IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate {
    private IWorkbenchWindow window;

    public SampleSwtAction() {
    }


    public void run(IAction action) {

    MessageDialog.openInformation(
            window.getShell(),
            "SampleSwt",
            "Hello,Run swt application");


        window.getShell().getDisplay().syncExec(
                  new Runnable() {
                    public void run(){
                        Display firstDisplay = new Display();   

                        Shell firstShell = new Shell(firstDisplay);
                        firstShell.setText("Sample SWT application");
                        firstShell.setSize(200,100);
                        firstShell.open ();
                            while (!firstShell.isDisposed()) {
                            if (!firstDisplay.readAndDispatch())
                                firstDisplay.sleep ();
                        }
                        firstDisplay.dispose ();
                    }
                  });



    }


    public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
    }


    public void dispose() {
    }

    public void init(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
        this.window = window;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you define a new `Display` '`firstDisplay`' within your `Runnable`.

Shouldn't' you also put a `syncExec(Runable)` for all actions (updating the UI) you are taking on that display?

---

Actually, the OP [Abhishek Choudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/552521/abhishek-choudhary) reports he doesn't need the extra display '`firstDisplay`' and performs all he need to do within the single `syncExec(Runable)`, with the default `Display`.

Comment: So is it not possible to provide the entire set of code in a single Runnable entry

Comment: @Abhishek: I don't think so, but I haven't tested it. Did you try that nested `syncExec` for your '`firstDisplay`'? Has the exception occurred again?

Comment: Hi. Finally I got the solution :) . Your point was correct as Display was already a UI Updating unit.

Comment: In a single one by considering the default Display. So it worked :)

Comment: @Abhishek: perfect. I have updated my answer to include your conclusion.